# Can't find static folder in express bundled by webpack (SSR)

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, server-side-rendering

I intend to do server side rendering in react with event handlers and I'm stuck on a problem on getting the index.js file be served in the localhost express server. Tried looking for several other answers here but I can't seem to wrap my head around this.

Here's the code.

```
import express from "express";
import React from "react";
import { renderToString } from "react-dom/server";
import App from "./app/home/app";
import path from "path";
import fs from "fs";

let server = port => {
  const app = express();

  app.use('/js', express.static(path.resolve('/static')));
  console.log(path.resolve('/static'));
  console.log(path.join(__dirname, '/static'));
  console.log(fs.existsSync(path.resolve('/static')));

  app.get("/", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send(renderMarkup(renderToString(<App />)));
  });

  app.get("/ping", (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).send("HELLO!");
  });

  app.listen(port, () => console.log("Server Ready!"));
}

let renderMarkup = html => {
  return `
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head>
            <title>Webpack SSR Demo</title>
            <meta charset="utf-8" />
        </head>
        <body>
            <div id="app">${html}</div>
            <script src="/js/index.js"></script>
        </body>
    </html>
 `;
}

server(process.env.PORT || 8080);
```

I tried logging if my static directory exists. It returns a false although when I check my build folder (the output directory of the webpack bundle. It does exist).

My build folder directory is described below (rest assured all js bundles are built successfully):

```
build
|- static
|-- index.js
|- server.js
```

TLDR: The view is successfully rendered. The events are not working because the client side javascript is not being loaded.

Comment: So if the app is being rendered successfully, what does your network in chrome dev tools say? Where is it trying to fetch the JS bundles?

Comment: localhost:8080/js/index.js it gives 404

Comment: .use(express.static(path.resolve(__dirname, '..', 'build'), { index: false, maxAge: 0 }))

Comment: it's still a 404 @joelgullander what was the idea behind '..'

Comment: Didn't see you had server.js inside your ./build folder

Comment: the path that you provide to the express.static function is relative to the directory from where you launch your node process.

Comment: Try removing the '..'

Comment: Apparently it's a webpack problem. I posted the answer. thanks for the help!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After scouring a lot of questions, github issues and reading the bundled js.

It wasn't a problem with the server code. 
See: https://github.com/webpack/webpack/issues/1599

I needed to add this to my webpack.server.js:

```
node: {
  __dirname: false,
},
```